# Instruction works outside of a function but not inside on ActionScript 2 Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

i dont know why this instruccion works when i write it in this way:

```
lv = new LoadVars();
lv.sVar1 = "value1";
lv.sVar2 = "value2";
lv.onLoad = onLoadCallBack;
lv.sendAndLoad("http://localhost/tiempo/flash/rsstoflash.php?" + new Date(), lv, "POST");
```

But if a put this code into a function in this way:

```
function carga() {
lv = new LoadVars();
lv.sVar1 = "value1";
lv.sVar2 = "value2";
lv.onLoad = onLoadCallBack;
lv.sendAndLoad("http://localhost/tiempo/flash/rsstoflash.php?" + new Date(), lv, "POST");
}
carga();
```

The compiler told me:

> Error opening URL
>   'file:///C|/webserver/www/tiempo/flash/undefined'
>   Error opening URL
>   'file:///C|/webserver/www/tiempo/flash/undefined'
>   Error opening URL
>   'file:///C|/webserver/www/tiempo/flash/undefined'

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be that of scope.

When you have your var lv declared inside of a function, it's a local variable.  So, it doesn't exist once the function that calls it is done.

So, this prevents lv's callback function from firing.

Assuming you have the function onLoadCallBack declared elsewhere in your code, a way to get around this would either be to declare `var lv = new LoadVars();` globally (ie, outside of the function), OR to make an array or some other global container to house instances of the loaders in (if you want to have multiple running at once, say).

Something like this would look like:

```
var lv_array = new Array();

function carga() {
var lv = new LoadVars();
lv.sVar1 = "value1";
lv.sVar2 = "value2";
lv.onLoad = onLoadCallBack;
lv.sendAndLoad("http://localhost/tiempo/flash/rsstoflash.php?" + new Date(), lv, "POST");
}
carga();
```

Comment: What does your onLoadCallBack function look like?